# Fantasy novel where the forces of good have prevailed and the "heroes" are assassins, thieves, etc

Tags: story-identification, novel, good-against-evil

I'm looking for the name of a fantasy novel I read once where the forces of good have prevailed and now everything is out of balance. I remember that the band of  "heroes"  consist of and assassin and a thief among others. The land was being subjected to the forces of good taken to an extreme, small offences leading to death, etc...

This has been bugging me for months, so if anyone know the name I would appreciate it.

[EDIT] 
I read the book more than 4 years ago, but I can't narrow it down more than that. It was set in a quasi medieval setting, by that I mean no technology, more traditional fantasy-ish. Unfortunately I don't remember the cover, or even if there were non-human races in it.

I am pretty sure the main character was an assassin however, as little help as that is.

Comment: can you include more details, like when you read the book, the cover or what kind of magic was used?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[*Villains By Necessity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villains_by_Necessity) by [Eve Forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_Forward) ([publication information](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7365)). Summary from the Wikipedia article:

> *Villains by Necessity* is a fantasy that takes place in a world in which good finally triumphs over evil. However, in this fantasy world where a complete purge of evil is achieved and darkness is almost unheard of, a druid discovers that this could be considered too much of a good thing. With the contrast of good and evil gone, the world has become unbalanced and dangerously unstable. In order to prevent reality from literally falling apart the druid must find a way to bring back the darkness, which the old heroes have locked away. To bring back the darkness the druid must gather a team of the few left alive willing to do so; a team of villains. Together these villains must step out of their comfort zone and work together to save the world from itself.

Comment: wow, the cover doesn't seem familiar at all but that is definitely it! Thanks!